# How not to execute functions when they are set as values in dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I tried to execute this part of code:

```
def func():
    print 'function is being called'

mapp=dict{'first': 'value_1','second':func()}
   

print mapp.get('first')
```

I expected to see output as `'value_1'`, but the function is also getting executed even though I am not explicitly calling it.
Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIloR.png)

How to make this dictionary so that, the function will not be executed when not called explicitly.

Comment: what do you want 'second' value to be? a handle to the function? if so, do `'second': func`

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

`func()` will call the function. If you want to get the function as a first-class object, then just use `func`. Example:

```py
mapp = {'first': 'value_1', 'second': func}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the function name in the dictionary without the parentheses, just the function name: `mapp=dict{'first': 'value_1', second':func}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func():
    print('function is being called')


def func_2(msg='No comment'):
    print(msg)


mapp = {'first': 'value_1', 'second': func, 'third': func_2, 'fourth': func_2}

print(mapp.get('first'))
mapp.get('second')()
mapp.get('third')()
mapp.get('fourth')('Yes, I have a lot to say')
```

Output

```
value_1
function is being called
No comment
Yes, I have a lot to say
```

Comment: You can extend the concept `mapp = {'first': 'value_1', 'second': func}` to as many functions as needed. Just no parentheses with the function name in the dictionary. The same function can be placed in the dictionary multiple times allowing the function to be called with and without parameters.

Comment: I need this dictionary more generic. Like I would always do `print mapp.get(incoming_param_from_somewhere)` . But in the above example in need to `mapp.get('second')()` if its a funciton and `mapp.get('first')` if its a literal.
Isn't there a way to create this dictionary as more generic.

Comment: Yes, there is. Of course in `print mapp.get(incoming_param_from_somewhere)`, `incoming_param_from_somewhere` will need to be a valid `key`. For instance, dictionaries are used to manage menu selections which determine which functions to run. They are also used to replace extended `if` and `elif` sequences.